# Instant Gratification and Self-Sabotage

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, self, self-cognition, cognitive-psychology, thinking

I notice that I often engage in activities that provide instant gratification and not do the work I am supposed to do. (I need to learn to delay gratification)

I also fall prey to obsessive overthinking,perfectionism, analysis paralysis, Information overload and FOMO.

I always wonder why we can't stop self-sabotage even if we know it's harmful.

Is there any sort of profound realization that will help us to overcome it? (Repeating|Thinking|Meditating on it)

Comment: A question for the psychology department.

Comment: I think psychology.stackexchange.com will close the question as a self-help question.

Comment: Just because it is not appropriate for the psychology group doesn't make it appropriate for the philosophy group.

Comment: I agree that the question is more suitable for psychology. Such actions usually serve some unconscious goals, and there are various techniques (or whole methods of therapy) aiming to avoid these diversions or find a healthy compromise with one's subconscious desires.

Comment: Become a Stoic.

Comment: It's no magic bullet, but turning your attentions to the plight of others sometimes has a way of alleviating the plight within yourself. You can find allusion to this in various religion and any number of self-help books, but in essence, it likely has something to do with the fact that when helping others, we act less hungrily, and so are not occupied so much with the continual seeking of dopamine we tend to engage in when we abandon ourselves to ourselves and become bored, lazy, anxious and addicted.

Comment: For me what has helped in this direction is the involvement in athletics. Wanting to have a fit body (not only appear fit but be fit), only way was to engage in consistent exercise and gymnastics/athletics. But involvement in athletics teaches one a basic thing, that result is not instant. Result will come only after sustained consistent effort. This is the lesson taught.

Answer (score 1):

Read "The Seven Habits of Highly Effective People" by Stephen Covey.

The problem here is the lack of recognition between desire and necessity. Of course, recognition is not enough. The only way to effectively change behavior is by habit. And the only way to acquire an habit is by means of proactivity. All of that is perfectly synthesized by Covey on this book.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the best question for philosophy stack exchange. You will find better answers listening to lectures on youtube or listening to psychology lectures.  ..quick advice, Instant gratification is a selfish act. Instant gratification is not caring about your future self. Overthinking and analysis paralysis can be helped with articulation, and often this involves more reading and exploring ideas in general. Exercise/ artistic expression helps with overthinking. Cheers